# How can I create groups in SQL based on a repeating category value?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So I have a table with timestamps and different categories [A,B,C,D] in Google Big Query. The thing is I want to group them with their respective timestamps but have more than one case. Each "group" would go from A-D with B or C being or not being there.

| Time Stamp | Category |
| --- | --- |
| 1:10 | A |
| 1:12 | B |
| 1:15 | D |
| 2:05 | A |
| 2:10 | D |

So in this example, there would be two groups.

One ranging from 1:10 - A to 1:15 - D and the second group from 2:05 - A to 2:10 - D.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Sample table data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result. i.e. a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

To generate the groups you need, You can use SQL [window function](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-window-functions/) to do that.

Step 1. Use window function and lag() to find out the previous row's category.

Step 2. Define when a new group should start. Based on provided data, a new group should start when category is A and previous row's category is D.  whenever we reach a new group, we use window function to increase the index by +1.

Step 3. Use group by operator on group_inex and min()/max() to get group_start,group_end condition, along with other aggregation function we want to perform in the data. In the above example, I add sum() on data column as demo purpose.

See the following code as an example:

```
with time_category_tracking AS (
select
   data_val,
   time_stamp,
   category,
   lag(category) over (order by time_stamp) as pre_category
from
   time_category_entry
),
time_categroy_group AS (
select
   data_val,
   time_stamp,
   category,
   SUM(case when category = 'A' AND coalesce(pre_category,'D') = 'D' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by time_stamp) as group_index
from
   time_category_tracking
)
select
   group_index,
   concat(min(time_stamp),' - ', min(category)) as group_start,
   concat(max(time_stamp),' - ', max(category)) as group_end,
   sum(data_val) as data_sum
from
   time_categroy_group
group by
   group_index
```

[SQLFIDDLE LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9d3a2/1)

[image]